# How can I minimize the numerical error in this summation?

Tags: c++, c++20, precision, numeric, numerical-methods

I'm suffering from a numerical error in the following [code example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=23f3437679d02162) (I've added the Kahan summation attempt and a more clever naive, but still naive version, below; but it's even worse unfortunately):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g{ rd() };
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> u;

    static std::size_t constexpr n = 1000;

    std::vector<double> q(n);
    std::generate_n(q.begin(), q.size(), [&]() { return u(g); });

    double average_of_q{};
    for (auto const& q : q)
        average_of_q += q;
    average_of_q /= n;

    std::vector<double> f(n);
    std::generate_n(f.begin(), n, [&]() { return u(g); });

    double sum1{};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum1 += std::abs(f[i] - q[i]);
    sum1 /= n;

    {
        double sum2{};
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            sum2 += std::abs(f[i] - q[i]) - q[i];
        sum2 = sum2 / n + average_of_q;

        std::cout << "naive: " << std::abs(sum1 - sum2) << std::endl;
    }
    {
        double sum2{},
            c{};
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            double const x = std::abs(f[i] - q[i]) - q[i] - c,
                s = sum2 + x;
            c = (s - sum2) - x;

            sum2 = s;
        }
        sum2 = sum2 / n + average_of_q;

        std::cout << "kahan: " << std::abs(sum1 - sum2) << std::endl;
    }
    {
        double sum2{};
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (f[i] - q[i] >= 0)
                sum2 += f[i] - 2 * q[i];
            else
                sum2 -= f[i];
        }
        sum2 = sum2 / n + average_of_q;

        std::cout << "more clever, but still naive: " << std::abs(sum1 - sum2) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is `1.11022e-16`, while we would theoretically expect that it should be `0`. How can I optimize this code such that `std::abs(sum1 - sum2)` is as small as possible?

To motivate this: In my actual application, I already know `average_of_q` and I don't need to iterate over every `i`, since I know that `std::abs(f[i] - q[i])` is extremely small for most of the `i`, which is why I need to want to use the formula for `sum2`.

**EDIT**: I've asked for the theoretic part of this question on MSE as well (but it's slightly different; I didn't want to make things too complicated here): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4688917/47771.

**EDIT 2:**
I've also tried to "boost" the terms of the sum by multiplying them with a factor:

```
{
    double sum2{};
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        sum2 += 1000 * (std::abs(f[i] - q[i]) - q[i]);
    sum2 = sum2 / (1000 * n) + average_of_q;

    std::cout << "boosted: " << std::abs(sum1 - sum2) << std::endl;
}
```

### **EDIT 3**:

It might be a useful information: In my actual application, many of the `f[i]` are small compared to `q[i]`. For simplicity, you can assume that all `q[i] = 1`, many of the `f[i]` are around 1e-10, but a few are close to `1`.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253391/discussion-on-question-by-0xbadf00d-how-can-i-minimize-the-numerical-error-in-th); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario basically boils down to comparing the accumulated round-off error between multiple mathematically equivalent ways of computing the same quantity. As had been pointed out in comments, in order to minimize the numerical difference when using finite-precision floating-point computation, the intermediate computation must be carried out in higher than target precision. In particular, in this code this needs to be applied to the computation of `average_of_q`, `sum1`, and `sum2`.

The target precision here is `double`, which *very likely* is mapped to the IEEE-754 `binary64` binary floating-point format. Various compilers offer some form of quadruple precision floating-point type, which may or may not be mapped to IEEE-754's `binary128`. For example, with the Intel compiler (`icl`), the type `_Quad` is offered, and works just fine for this code. However, a more portable solution could use [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) to accumulate in *quasi*-quadruple precision. This is demonstrated below.

From a software perspective it is important to instruct the compiler to *not* re-associate floating-point expressions, so as to preserve the numerical properties of Kahan summation. The command-line flags to enforce that differ by compiler, in my case it is `/fp:strict`, and the entire compiler invocation for the code below was `icl /W4 /Ox /QxHOST /fp:strict array_sum_issue.cpp`

With `n=1000000` the difference |`sum1 - sum2`| is usually 0, but occasionally 2<sup>-54</sup> corresponding to double-precision epsilon.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g{ rd() };
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> u;

    static std::size_t constexpr n = 1000000;

    std::vector<double> q(n);
    std::generate_n(q.begin(), q.size(), [&]() { return u(g); });

    double average_of_q{};
    {
        double sum = 0, c = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            double y = q[i] - c;
            double t = sum + y;
            c = (t - sum) - y;
            sum = t;
        }
        average_of_q = sum / n;
    }

    std::vector<double> f(n);
    std::generate_n(f.begin(), n, [&]() { return u(g); });

    double sum1{};
    {
        double sum = 0, c = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            double y = std::abs(f[i] - q[i]) - c;
            double t = sum + y;
            c = (t - sum) - y;
            sum = t;
        }
        sum1 = sum / n;
    }

    double sum2{};
    {
        double sum = 0, c = 0;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            double y = (std::abs(f[i] - q[i]) - q[i]) - c;
            double t = sum + y;
            c = (t - sum) - y;
            sum = t;
        }
        sum2 = std::fma (sum, 1.0 / n, average_of_q);
    }
    double diff = std::abs (sum1 - sum2);
    printf ("average_of_q = % 23.16e (% 23.13a)\n", average_of_q, average_of_q);
    printf ("sum1         = % 23.16e (% 23.13a)\n", sum1, sum1);
    printf ("sum2         = % 23.16e (% 23.13a)\n", sum2, sum2);
    printf ("|sum1-sum2|  = % 23.16e (% 23.13a)\n", diff, diff);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Sample output from the above program (numerical values will differ a bit based on the random numbers generated):

```
average_of_q =  5.0031728235599426e-01 (   0x1.0029963aaf686p-1)
sum1         =  3.3347262871877092e-01 (   0x1.5579d949d5452p-2)
sum2         =  3.3347262871877092e-01 (   0x1.5579d949d5452p-2)
|sum1-sum2|  =  0.0000000000000000e+00 (   0x0.0000000000000p+0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I replace `std::mt19937 g{ rd() };` by `std::mt19937 g{ 0 };`, then the output of `diff` is `5.55112e-17`. Why is that?

Comment: Computations that return zero mathematically do not usually do so when implemented via finite-precision floating-point arithmetic. Different sequences of inputs will lead to different outputs with differing amounts or error. Use of Kahan summation *reduces* the accumulated error, it does not eliminate it completely and `sum/n` adds new error. 5.55e-17 means 2**(-54). The IEEE-754 double format has 53 significant bits (52 of which are being stored, 1 implicit). We are at the precision limit. You should see a difference of 1 in the least significant digit of the hex float output on the right.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Highly recommended reading: Nicholas J. Higham, *Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, 2nd ed.*, SIAM 2002

Comment: Can you give an advice when I really need to use Kahan's algorithm and when ordinary summation is sufficient? Also: In which scenario do I need to use `std::fma`? And does it matter whether we use `std::fma(a, b, c)` or `std::fma(b, a, c)` (algebraically clearly not, but I could imagine that one is preferred over the other when `a` or `b` is negative or an integer).

Comment: @0xbadf00d Use Kahan summation when (1) you are very much concerned about results that mathematically should be zero but are close to floating-point epsilon when computed in floating-point arithmetic (this is usually *not* an issue in practical terms) or (2) there are significant numerical differences between simple summation and Kahan summation. `fma(a,b,c) == fma(b,a,c)`. Use FMA if you have a product *a \* b + c*, where there is a risk of subtractive cancellation between *(a \* b)* and *c*. A good book on practical numerical analysis will bring you up to speed; I already recommended one.